# How can I display current product attribute in a callout phtml file?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, attributes, catalog, model, registry

There is a callout phtml file called in my right sidebar (let's call it attribute.phtml), on the product page.

I'm trying to show the attribute value in that callout.

The attribute is a drop down, so it should be

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('attributecode'); ?>
```

But I am missing something before that, I'm wondering how can I load it for the current product ? Note: this is not inside list or view , it's in template/callouts . I'm stuck, any help would be really appreciated right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product should be available from the registry:

```
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
```

You should then be able to pull any required attributes straight out of it:

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('attributecode');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before your code:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
```

You should then be able to call things based on product attributes... (here's an example that creates a shipping price callout based on product weight and price - this actually calls static blocks that have been created via Magento's adminhtml)

```
<?php if ($_product->getweight() > "155.0000" && $_product->getweight() < "187.0000"): ?>
  <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('flat50')->toHtml() ?>
<?php elseif ($_product->getweight() > "186.0000" && $_product->getweight() < "208.0000"): ?>
  <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('flat100')->toHtml() ?>
<?php elseif ($_product->getweight() < "156.0000" && $_product->getPrice() > "39.00"): ?>
  <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('fship')->toHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```